# Reference Metadata field with JSON Formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, formatting, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am unable to capture the Managed Metadata field within my JSON formatting. I can reference other fields by their Internal names but how would I go about grabbing that MMD value?

```
{
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "iconName": "OpenInNewWindow",
    "class": "sp-field-quickAction",
    "href": {
      "operator": "+",
      "operands": [
        "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/newsite/Lists/listname/AllItems.aspx?ID=",
        "[$Custom_x0020_Field]"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The link doesn't generate which means there must be an error in the code. The Managed Metadata field is probably an object so what attribute can I reference to get the set value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed Metadata type of field is not supported in column formatting.

**Supported column types**

**The following column types support column formatting:**

Single line of text

Number

Choice

Person or Group

Yes/No

Hyperlink

Picture

Date/Time

Lookup

Title (in Lists)

**The following are not currently supported:**

Managed Metadata

Filename (in Document Libraries)

Calculated

Retention Label

Currency

Reference: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: It looks like Managed Metadata columns are now supported:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#supported-column-types